# Using Index and Match to return corresponding values from a row of data and repeat for next

Tags: indexing, match, scheduling, mailmerge

I am trying to create a macro to produce a production schedule to deliver material hour by hour in the required quantity. The data below is scrubbed and cleaned from the MRP system. 
[Raw Data : Initial Data in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4JPz.jpg)

I am trying to use the index function to get the hour for the corresponding part number in the column "`hour`"

```
=INDEX($C$1:$N$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C2:N2<>0,),0))
```

The index function works, but only returns the first matching instance for each row.

After getting the data in column "`hour`", I am using a 2 dimensional lookup to get the data from the matrix.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, $B1:$N2, MATCH(O2,$B$1:$N$1, 0), FALSE)
```

The end goal is to get the data as shown below to use it as a source for mail merge.

I need help to to correct the index match function to show all data so i can create mail merge and print individual tickets for a part number with corresponding quantity and the hour in which it needs to be delivered.

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4m5G.jpg)